# Get frequency information from PCM data

Tags: python, python-2.x, pcm, frequency-analysis

Let's say I use the `wave` module to get raw PCM data from a sound file. How can I compute the amplitude of the contained frequencies of a specific sample? I later want to draw a frequency graph like this for every frame:

[image: Frequency Graph Image]

How can the amplitudes of each frequency be calculated?

If possible, I would prefer a solution that does not require `numpy`. A link to learning resources on the background of the computations necessary for this operation would be quite helpful as well.

Comment: The answer is relaxing your fear of `numpy` as soon as possible (unless you have a VERY compelling reason), and use `numpy.fft.rfft()`.

Comment: If you want a resource, check the excellent "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" book. You can't get a better explanation of frequency analysis using FFT.

Comment: [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing By Steven W. Smith, Ph.D.](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm) is an excellent resource IMHO.  Take the time to start from the beginning, even if it seems rudimentary.

Comment: You could [compute the DFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) -- but only if you don't care about `O(N**2)` performance. How about using [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org) via ctypes?

Answer (score 1):

For calculating amplitudes from each frequency taking a raw PCM file, you have to do the [Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform). Since you don't want to use `numpy`, you can use `pylab` as an alternative [as can be seen here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/10152/spectrogram-of-wav-file). Give it a try!

Update: the `pylab.specgram` docs [are here](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.specgram).

Comment: Pylab depends on Numpy, doesn't it?

Comment: @heltonbiker Yes it does.